# How do I search shell command history with a text editor?

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-history

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> let's you search command history, but it's a little primitive. Is there a way to export all my command history (not just the current terminal session, but the full history) to a text file? I could then use a text editor to search it comfortably. Or if the history file already exists, where is it?

Comment: I'm going to assume that you meant your shell's command history, and have edited to use the default shell, bash.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/sh.1.html):

```
HISTFILE
    The name of the file in which command history is saved.
    The default value  is  ~/.bash_history.
    If unset, the command history is not saved when a shell exits.
```

So, the variable `HISTFILE` will contain the filename where the history will be saved.

```
$ echo "$HISTFILE"
/home/user/.bash_history
```

You can now search for the pattern:

```
$ grep "vim" "$HISTFILE"
vim foo.text
vim bar.text
vim file.txt
```

As @Dennis has pointed out, if you want you can run `history -a` to append the command history of the running session to the `$HISTFILE` file. Basically the commands will be automatically appended once you close a session, `history -a` will do the same thing right at that instant.

Run `help history` to get more idea on the `history` builtin itself.

Comment: Note that the history file will usually not contain lines entered since the beginning of the current bash session, which can be fixed by executing `history -a`.

Comment: @Dennis: Good point..added..

Answer (score 4):

The bash history is saved in your home directory `~/.bash_history`.

Basically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> searches from this file.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
history > output.txt
less output.txt
```

Then search by typing `/` + `searchterm`